# Bash race condition with status updates

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script to monitor Docker containers. The two useful commands are `docker ps` and `docker events`. `docker ps` will list all the containers and their statuses. `docker events` will warn me about changes in status.

My script will first call `docker ps`, parse the output, and then call `docker events` to wait for future updates. The issue arises when the status of a container changes in between these two calls. What's the best way to avoid this so called race condition?

Comment: I don't really see the race condition. `docker ps` may contain containers that are no longer present at the time you call `docker events` vice versa. So?

Comment: @S.Pinkus Because I might miss a status change, I need to detect this, somehow.